# Determining requester's IP address in RPC call

Tags: go, rpc

In Go using the standard `net/rpc` functionality, I would like to determine what the IP address an inbound RPC request is coming from.  The underlying `http` functionality appears to provide this in the `http.Request` object, but I cannot see any way of getting at that from the default RPC handler (set using `rpc.HandleHTTP`).

Is there some hidden mechanism for getting at the underlying `http.Request`, or do I have to do something fancier with setting up a different HTTP responder?

Comment: Why do you want the ip address?

Comment: @JeremyWall I need it for logging/debugging purposes, and it would be nice to have for a simple integrity check on something too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use https://github.com/valyala/gorpc instead of net/rpc, which passes client address to RPC server handler - see http://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/gorpc#HandlerFunc for details.

Comment: Thanks! The project I was working on close to three years ago is long gone for me, but this will hopefully be useful for people with the same question in the future.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it is not possible to grab the address from somewhere in the default server.

The [service call method](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/rpc/server.go#L346), which calls the request receiving function, does not provide any access to the remote data stored in the codec.

If http handlers could be registered twice ([which they can't](http://play.golang.org/p/xQiIwf60Aw)), you could have overwritten the `DefaultRPCPath` for the HTTP Handler setup by [`HandleHTTP`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/rpc/server.go#L650). But that's simply [not possible today](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L956).

What you can do, without much fuss, is to build a RPC server based on the default one with your own `ServeHTTP` method:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/rpc"
)

type myRPCServer struct {
   *rpc.Server
}

func (r *myRPCServer) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   log.Println(req.RemoteAddr)
   r.Server.ServeHTTP(w, req)
}

func (r *myRPCServer) HandleHTTP(rpcPath, debugPath string) {
    http.Handle(rpcPath, r)
}

func main() {
    srv := &myRPCServer{rpc.NewServer()}
    srv.HandleHTTP(rpc.DefaultRPCPath, rpc.DefaultDebugPath)

    // ...http listen code...
}
```

The downside of this, is of course, that you can't use `rpc.Register` anymore. You have to write `srv.Register`.

**Edit:** I forgot that you'd need to write your own `HandleHTTP` as well. The reason for this is, that if you embed the RPC server and you write `srv.HandleHTTP` it is called on the embedded instance, passing the embedded instance to `http.Handle()`, ignoring your own definition of `ServeHTTP`. This has the drawback, that you won't have the ability to debug your RPC server using the debug path, as the server's `HandleHTTP` uses a [private debug handler](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/rpc/server.go#L644) (`rpc.debugHTTP`) which you can't access.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, and kind of what I figured would be necessary. I'm a total newbie to Go, though, so it might be a while before I can make the pieces fit together.

Answer (score 1):

The `net/rpc` package is at a higher level of abstraction than tcp or http. Since it can use multiple codecs it doesn't make sense for it to offer a way to get at the ip address of the inbound rpc. It's theoretically possible someone could implement a code that talks on unix sockets instead or using radio transmitters.

If you want access to specifics of the transport layer you will have to drop a level in the stack and use `net` or `net/http` directory to make your rpc service.

Comment: I figured that it was at a higher level of abstraction, but there's no reason there can't be an interface to get at the underlying transport mechanism.  The API as it stands right now doesn't seem to provide any future hooks for that, although presumably the interface of the handler's stub typename would become that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is currently no way to do this in rpc function. 
See this [link](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4584) for more info

Here is a summary.

Q:

> Right now RemoteAddr() method can be called to get the RPC client's address only on
>   net.Conn when the client dials to server, but suppose that your server has multiple
>   clients connected and each of this clients are calling an RPC exported method. Is there
>   a way to implement a method to get the caller's remote address from inside the RPC
>   method?
>
> func (t *Type) Method(args *Args, reply *string) error {
>          //something like
>             *reply = Caller.RemoteAddr().String()
>             // who called the method now?
>          return nil
>      }

A:

> I'm skeptical. It would take an API change (not necessarily a backwards incompatible one
>   but still a bit of a redesign) to supply this.